# I am trying to deploy my mern stack blog application on vercel but getting CORS Policy error

Tags: node.js, express, frontend, cors, backend

I am deploying my mern blog website project on vercel, I deployed the backend and then frontend but when I open the given url by vercel I am getting this following error :

**Access to fetch at 'https://blog-website-server-delta.vercel.app/profile' from origin 'https://aakash-blog-website.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Also I used cors in my backend index.js file
app.use(cors())

How can I solve this error?

I tried to add the frontend url origin in the cors but it didn't work.
I want that my frontend should succesfully fetch the data from the backend.